# Polarized epithelium and localization of ion channels

Tags: physiology, cell-biology

I'm trying to learn more about polarized epithelial cells of the gut. I am familiar with classic brush border transporters localized to the apical memebrane to facilitate nutrient absorption. I am wondering though, where are ion channels located? I would guess basolaterally since they would be exposed to the extracellular space. I would appreciate a primary reference showing the location of voltage-gated channels in particular as I could not find them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's a first for me. I wouldn't have guessed gut cells would have voltage-gated channels.
This article describes voltage-gated sodium channels on both the luminal and basolateral membranes:

Barshack, I., Levite, M., Lang, A., Fudim, E., Picard, O., Ben Horin, S., & Chowers, Y. (2008). Functional voltage-gated sodium channels are expressed in human intestinal epithelial cells. Digestion, 77(2), 108-117.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18391489

Comment: Thanks for the suggested article. I'm not able to get it through my institution, do you have a copy, or can you quote the relevant results?

Comment: Check your email, Leonardo.